# Input from Entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting the error unknown option "-command". Please help! (I am trying to get an input from my Entry box (Input).

```
from tkinter import *

def input_One():
    inputOne = self.Input_.get("1.0",'end-1c')
root = Tk()

Input_ = Entry(root,command=input_One)
Input_.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=8)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, post the text here on SO instead. And your question needs some context. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay, like this?

Comment: what is `self`?

Comment: I don't know, found it on another post? I am trying to save the input from Input_ into a variable.

Comment: If you do not understand what *your code* does then first try to understand your code, goodbye, do not waste people's time, I do not know what kind of response you expect if you do not understand *your code*.

Comment: the function name variable is called input_One, whereas the other is called inputOne

Comment: An `Entry` does not have a `command=` option - what would that even mean?  You probably want a `Button`, which does have such an option.

Comment: I want to be able to type something in, and then save what I type in into a variable.

Comment: What do you expect `command=input_One` to do for an input widget? When do you expect the command will be run?

Comment: `Entry` widgets don't have a `command` option. One way to do something like what you want would be to also create a separate `Button` widget—which does have a `command` option—and have it execute your function to retrieve the data when it's clicked/pressed.

Comment: **_WHEN_** do you want to get your input? I never get the lack of time spec. in these questions...

Comment: Sorry for the broadness ect, I will take that into account when asking my next question! Thanks for the response anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Martineau` pointed out, entry widgets have no `command` function. Instead, you should create a tkinter variable and run a trace on it as shown below:

```
from tkinter import *

def input_One():
    inputOne = Input_.get()
root = Tk()

Input_ = StringVar ()
Entry(root, textvariable = Input_).grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=8)
Input_.trace ("w", lambda a, b, c: input_One ())

root.mainloop()
```